# css for a very simplistic html

Tags: css

I am putting together a web page that is very basic and really only focusing on the data.

It involves h1 - h3 and within there paragraphs and unordered lists.

I am currently not specifying any styling, but I would like to take an existing css and use it with little to no modification. In essence, improving the standard browser presentation.

I tried 960.gs reset and text.css but it still did not look very "polished". Something typography heavy would most likely help...

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap is a new reset/base CSS offering from Twitter (just recently open sourced).  I've started using it on a few projects and love it. Here's the example typography: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#typography

Answer (score 1):

For you, I recommend [Flutie](https://github.com/thoughtbot/flutie).

A straight link to the CSS file: https://raw.github.com/thoughtbot/flutie/master/app/assets/stylesheets/flutie.css

Comment: There an example of this somewhere?

Comment: I googled the blog entry where Thoughtbot introduced flutie and go here: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/762048192/flutie. A screencap of the resultant styles are here: http://ui.thoughtbot.com/assets/flutie-default.png. Of course, it's not as if you can't just try it out. Just put it into your current stylesheet, and if you don't like it, throw it out.

Comment: It's worth nothing that one thing Flutie doesn't do that you might want is add sensible padding to the page. You're going to want to do that manually through something like adding `<style>body {padding: 20px;}</style>` to your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I use this one on every project, and it works fine :

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [Blueprint CSS Framework](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) or search for `css framework` in a search engine.